# Can I do "special subscribe" to one of the properties in Vue2?

Tags: vuejs2

I have view component that displays info about RECORD. This component contains contains some properties for description of user interactions with view (let's say it is `lastPushedButton`). So I need to reset this `lastPushedButton` property when view is receiving new RECORD's model. I have tried to use `updated` event but then it resets `lastPushedButton` everytime something changed, not only RECORD.

What is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `record` is passed in via a property to your component?

What you probably want is a `watch` on your property variable: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

```
watch: {
  record: function (newValue, oldValue) {
     this.lastPushedButton = ''
  }
},
```